# Opening blob in new window failing if file larger than 1MB or so

Tags: reactjs, blob

I am building a react project where a user needs to be able to preview a document that has been uploaded. I have the file stored in a blob file in a variable called  'upload', and I use the following code to display it in a new tab when the user clicks on the preview button:

```
var newWIndow;
if (upload.includes("data:application/pdf"))
    newWIndow = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + upload + "'></iframe>"
else
    newWIndow = "<img width='100%' src='" + upload + "'></img>";
var x = window.open();
x.document.open();
x.document.write(newWIndow);
x.document.close();
```

The uploads are limited to image or pdf files, and works great, except when the file size goes over 1MB. In that case, it simply opens a blank page:

[image]

THe entire blob file is too large to post here, but I thought that giving an idea of what it looks like might help someone spot what I am doing wrong, so here is a snippet:

data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoNPDwvTWV0YWRhdGEgMiAwIFIvUGFnZXMgMyAwIFI

Does anyone perhaps have any advice for me? Is there a better way to open the uploaded document? Is there a way to get around the size issue? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken, I was not using a blob object but a binary Base64 one. The new question, as well as the solution, is posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933052/base64-binary-data-in-an-url-string-opening-blank-page-if-file-too-large) post.